# Populate a dropbox in PHP using MySQL and then display the data in a table after clicking submit button

Tags: php, mysql, dropbox

I can populate correctly the dropbox but I cannot find a way to display the data of the selected item in a table when I click submit. Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Αναζήτηση Οφειλών Ανά Πολυκατοικία</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tbl_style.css" type ="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="search.php">
  <?php
    include('config.php');
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT odos FROM ofeiles_results ORDER BY odos ASC";
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo "<select name='polykatoikia'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['odos'] . "'>" . $row['odos'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
  ?>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Select" />
  </form>
</html>
</body>
```

So far so good, the dropbox gets populated. Then in the file search.php I have the following code:

**search.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Αποτελεσματα Αναζητησης Πολυκατοικιων</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tbl_style.css" type ="text/css"/>
</head>
</html>
<?php
  include('config_barcode.php');
  if(isset($_POST['select'])){
    $odoss = $_POST['select'];
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $display_query = "SELECT odos FROM ofeiles_results WHERE odos LIKE '" . $odoss . "'";
    $result_exoda = mysql_query($display_query) or die(mysql_error());
    print $result_exoda;
    $odos = $row['odos'];
    $app = $row['perigrafh'];
    $enoikos = $row['enoikos'];
    $mhnas = $row['mhnas'];
    $synolo = $row['synolo'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "<table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th align='center' bgcolor='#FFCC00'><strong>Οδος</strong></th>";
    echo "<th align='center' bgcolor='#FFCC00'><strong>Διαμερισμα</strong></th>";
    echo "<th align='center' bgcolor='#FFCC00'><strong>Όνομα</strong></th>";
    echo "<th align='center' bgcolor='#FFCC00'><strong>Σύνολο</strong></th>";
    echo "<th align='center' bgcolor='#FFCC00'><strong>Μήνας</strong></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$odos."</td>";
    echo " <td align='center'>".$app."</td>";
    echo " <td align='center'>".$enoikos."</td>";
    echo " <td align='center'>".$mhnas."</td>";
    echo " <td align='center'>".$synolo."</td>";
    echo "</table></td>";
    echo $result_exoda;
  }
?>
```

All I get is a blank page. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: a blank page would suggest you have error checking or display turned off

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions use PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to display the data in tables, you don't need to use many "echo" use LOOPS 
you can add more rows in

```
$sql = "SELECT your_row , another_row , your_row_again FROM your_table_name";
```

if you had more rows in you database.

```
 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser);
if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
$sql = "SELECT your_row , another_row , your_row_again FROM your_table_name";
mysql_select_db('your_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
echo "<div align = 'center'><table border = '1'>";
echo "<th>Your_row_Header</th><th>Row_Header_again</th><th>Row_Header_again</th>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<tr><td align = center>{$row['Your_row1']}</td>".
        "<td align = center>{$row['Your_Row2']}</td></tr>".
                       "<td align = center>{$row['Your_Row3']}</td>";
} 
echo "</table></div><br />";
mysql_close($conn);
```